# Forcing Google Cloud's Datastore datetimes to default to UTC

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime, google-cloud-datastore, timezone-offset

According to the datastore [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#DateTimeProperty), datetimes are always stored and returned in UTC.

However, in the cloud dashboard, all my datetimes are displayed in `CEST`, i.e. `UTC+2`.

When saving the entities, I do not include any timezone and use `datetime.utcnow()`.

To be more specific, here is my `TimeZonedDateTimeProperty` model, extending/partially overriding google's own `db.DateTimeProperty`:

```
class TimeZonedDateTimeProperty(db.DateTimeProperty):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TimeZonedDateTimeProperty, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __get__(self, model_instance, model_class):
        """Returns the value for this property on the given model instance."""

        if model_instance is None:
            return self

        attr_to_return = None

        try:
            # access the db.DateTimeProperty's getter

            attr_to_return = getattr(model_instance, super(TimeZonedDateTimeProperty, self)._attr_name())
        except AttributeError:
            attr_to_return = None

        if attr_to_return:
            # super methods of db.DateTimeProperty will be calling this 
            # getter too and we don't wanna mess up
            # the UTC convention when working with datetimes

            includes_correct_caller = None

            try:
                # after noticing that this getter is also being called
                # outside of user requests, inspect the caller and decide
                # whether to offset the UTC datetime or not 

                includes_correct_caller = "main_class_name" in str(inspect.stack()[1][0].f_locals["self"].__class__)
            except Exception:
                includes_correct_caller = False

            if includes_correct_caller:
                return attr_to_return + relativedelta(hours=+2)
            else:
                return attr_to_return
        else:
            return None
```

And here's an example usage in a subclassed `db.Model`:

```
class Message(db.Model):
    ...
    sent = TimeZonedDateTimeProperty()
    ...


m = Message(...
            sent=datetime.utcnow(),
            ...)
m.put()
```

Now, if I call a `m.sent` running on localhost, things go as planned, i.e. the `sent` property is saved in UTC and the getter returns an offset datetime.

In the live/production environment, the properties are **not** being saved in UTC and, consequently, the overridden getter unnecessarily adds 2 hours.

So:

- How can I force the live datastore to always use UTC when saving and serving my datetimes?
- Is my approach correct? Assuming it is, is there a more elegant way to handle timezoned datetimes in GAE?

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the cloud dashboard, I think this is just a matter of representation.  We have (ndb) models that record a timestamp using `ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_add=True)`; in the cloud dashboard the timestamp is displayed as local time: 2017-06-10 (21:36:07.917) BST, but if I print the timestamp in the remote shell the time is equivalent to UTC: 2017-06-10 20:36:07.917540.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949938/why-do-datastore-datetimes-look-different-in-appengine-console-vs-appengine-dash

Comment: OK, the dashboard representation is understandable.

But it still seems as if my getter is being called on `put()` or `put_async()` -- although I have a hunch this is not standard practice. But there is hardly any explanation for the duplicate +2hrs addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question, App Engine already stores times as UTC.

To address the second question, the approach in the question and the OP's answer will cause problems in the future:

- it will produce incorrect values when Central European Summer Time (CEST) ends and Central European Time (CET) begins
- inspecting the stack to avoid compounding the offset may not work for example if `Message.sent` is retrieved in another object's `put` method
- it will cause complications if the application grows to use more timezones

These problems can be avoided by storing datetimes in a standard DateTimeProperty, and converting them to timezone aware datetimes when required.

The [db docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses) suggest a solution for the OP's use case:

> If you only convert values to and from a particular time zone, you can
>   implement a custom datetime.tzinfo to convert values from the
>   datastore

Implementing custom `tzinfo`'s can be tricky, but tzinfos are already implemented in the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package.

The model could have a method that returns the timezone aware datetime:

```
from dateutil import tz
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Message(db.Model):

    sent = db.DateTimeProperty()

    def local_sent(self, default_tz='Europe/Paris'):
        """
        Returns a timezone-aware datetime for the local
        timezone.  
        The default timezone can be overridden to support
        other locales. 
        """
        utc = tz.gettz('UTC')
        local = tz.gettz(tz)    # or some other CET timezone
        return self.sent.replace(tzinfo=utc).astimezone(local)
```

Usage:

```
m = Message(sent=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
m.sent
datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 16, 18, 0, 12, 364017)
m.local_sent()
datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 16, 20, 0, 12, 364017, tzinfo=tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris'))
m.local_sent.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z %Z')
'2017-06-16 20:00:12.364017 +0200 CEST'

m = Message(sent=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
2017-06-16 18:15:33.555208
2017-06-16 18:15:33.555208  
m.local_sent('Asia/Beijing')
datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 17, 2, 15, 33, 555208, tzinfo=tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Beijing'))
m.local_sent('Asia/Beijing').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z %Z')
'2017-06-17 02:15:33.555208 +0800 CST'
```

This approach provides correct daylight saving time behaviour, avoids potentially fragile workarounds and handles most timezones.

Answer (score 4):

Google Datastore **does** store all dates/times in UTC(0). However, the cloud dashboard is keyed to your machine's timezone, so dates are rendered based on the timezone your operating system is set to. If you're on a Window's based system try changing the timezone and then refresh the dashboard. You'll find that any date properties on a listed entity will be updated to reflect your system's new timezone.

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

Based on the fact that the getter is indeed being called outside of the standard `get` requests and especially while `put()` is being executed, simply observe the call stack and look for the `put` keyword.

In other words, prevent the UTC timestamp modification before it's properly saved in the DB.

```
...

includes_correct_caller = None

try:
    _, _, _, stack_trace, _, _ = zip(*list(inspect.stack()))
    includes_correct_caller = "put" not in stack_trace    
except Exception:
    includes_correct_caller = False

if includes_correct_caller:
    return attr_to_return + relativedelta(hours=+2)
else:
    return attr_to_return
```